# Android: Updating drawable folder

Tags: android, database, drawable

right now I am developing an application and it has some set of images in a server machine. Is there anyway to update the drawables folder at application startup, so these images will have some ID in the R file (I am sliding the drawables in an imageview, image changes with duration in an ImageView). I prefer to store images in a central machine so that all tablets connected to the database will pick the images from a central machine at application startup or check it periodically. Otherwise every tablet needs to get reinstalled everytime I add some advertisement image to the drawables folder.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cant update drawable folders from code. You can use web service to pull the image and use it as image source of the image view.
Here is an example [How to load an ImageView by URL in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)

Comment: Could u please give an example about what u said so that we clearly understand....